# Property of modules via exact sequences

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules, homological-algebra

Suppose $A\neq 0$ is a commutative ring with $1$. Let $L, M, N$ be $A$-modules such that the sequence
$$0\longrightarrow L\overset{\alpha}{\longrightarrow} M\overset{\beta}{\longrightarrow} N\longrightarrow 0$$
is exact. Furthermore suppose $P$ is some property of an $A$-module (e.g. $P$ = Noetherian, Artinian, finitely generated, etc.) Now, I will say $P$ is "middle-property" if the following is true:
$$
M \textrm{ satisfies property } P \Longleftrightarrow L \textrm{ and } N \textrm{ satisfies property }P.
$$

Using this terminology, in "Undergraduate Commutative Algebra" by Miles Reid, it is proved that (in page 53) the property $P$ = Noetherian is "middle-property". I have the following questions

> 1) Is there standard name for what I called "middle-property"?
>
> 2) What are some other examples of "middle-property"? I have remarked
>   above that being Noetherian is "middle-property". Are being Artinian, free,
>   finitely-generated, flat, projective, injective, etc. are also
>   "middle-property"?

I realize that I have put awful lot of questions out there. Answering any one of them is greatly appreciated :) Basically, I would like to have a list of important  "middle-properties".

Thanks.

**Edit.** I just realized the following: If $A$ is a Noetherian ring, then property $P$ = "finitely-generated" is also "middle property". Indeed, being Noetherian and finitely-generated are equivalent for modules over Noetherian rings (See Corollary 3.5 part (ii) in "Undergraduate Commutative Algebra" by Miles Reid, page 53). So answers that illustrate "middle-property" for particular class of rings are also welcome.

Comment: Aside: another useful thing to consider is "if any two have property P, then so does the third".

Comment: @Hurkyl: That's interesting! (Since it is a weaker condition than "middle-property", I suspect more properties would satisfy it)

Comment: If $P$ is a "middle property" then the modules having property $P$ are a [Serre subcategory](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Serre+subcategory) of the category of all modules. [Thick subcategory](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/thick+subcategory) is another name used for those by some authors, as is the French name *épaisse*. However, other authors use the same words for the weaker condition Hurkyl is talking about.

Comment: @Martin: Thanks! This essentially answers question 1).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. The corresponding subcategories of modules are called [thick subcategories](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/thick+subcategory).
2. Artinian and noetherian modules satisfy this property, you can check this directly. The short exact sequence $0 \to \mathbb{Z} \xrightarrow{p} \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/p \to 0$ (for $p>1$) shows that free, projective and flat modules do not satisfy the property. It also fails for injective modules (look at $0 \to \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z} \to 0$) and for finitely generated modules (take some non-noetherian ring $A$, some non-finitely generated ideal $I$ and look at $0 \to I \to A \to A/I \to 0$).

Comment: Thanks Martin! What a complete answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

Artinian is a "middle-property". I think the rest of the properties you mention are not "middle-properties".